# Errors when using inheritance C++

Tags: c++, function, inheritance

So I have a 3D tic tac toe game and it runs fine running off of one class. When I try and make another class and put my cpu() function in there I ger some problems. The user can input their selection and it works fine but once the cpu() goes junk code is printed on the screen instead of x,0, or numbers but the grid is displayed fine.

my one class

```
class TTT {
      public: //defines functions in class
            void setup();
            void display();
            //void cpu();
            void player();
            void check(int); 

      protected: //sets variables only acessable in this class
                 int cp; //counts cpu points
            int pp; //counts player points
              char board[9]; //spots on board
              char board2[9];
              char board3[9];
              char xo[2]; //xo[0] = comp ||| xo[1] = human
              int rn; //picks who goes first
              int won;//if game has been won or tied
              int turn;//keeps track of whos turn
              int rc;//random placement by cpu
              int full;//tracks board to see if full
              int b1f; //board is full?
              int b2f;
              int b3f;


};
```

I tried taking out the cpu(); function and placing it in a new class that inherits the first

```
class CPUClass : public TTT{

      public:
      void cpu();

      };
```

My new cpu(); function below

```
void CPUClass::cpu(){
//stuff happens in here
}
```

When I call the cpu(); function in another function I use

```
CPUClass cc;
cc.cpu();
```

When I need to call the cpu() function in the cpu() function I just use cpu();

The values for my board arrays just seem to be null or something after the user goes.

I can post the full source if needed but I tried summarizing

Am I just inheriting wrong, do I need to add a virtual function, any help would be great.

Thanks.

Full code as requested

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <time.h> //seeding random
#include <windows.h> //allows for Sleep()

using namespace std;


class TTT {
      public: //defines functions in class
            void setup();
            void display();
            void cpu();
            void player();
            void check(int); 

      protected: //sets variables only acessable in this class
                 int cp; //counts cpu points
            int pp; //counts player points
              char board[9]; //spots on board
              char board2[9];
              char board3[9];
              char xo[2]; //xo[0] = comp ||| xo[1] = human
              int rn; //picks who goes first
              int won;//if game has been won or tied
              int turn;//keeps track of whos turn
              int rc;//random placement by cpu
              int full;//tracks board to see if full
              int b1f; //board is full?
              int b2f;
              int b3f;


};

class CPUClass : public TTT{


      void cpu();

      };

class CPUClass2 : public TTT{

      //void cpu2();

      };      

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    TTT ttt; //allows class to be acessable

    cout << "Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe!" << endl; 
    cout << "Three in a row wins [vertical, horizontal, diagonal]" << endl;

    ttt.setup();//calls setup function in class TTT


}

void TTT::setup(){ //sets up board and all variables

     won = 0;  //game not won q = won/tied
     full = 0; //9 = board is full
     cp = 0;
     pp =0;
     b1f = 0;
     b2f = 0;
     b3f=0;

     board[0] = '1'; //sets up the board
     board[1] = '2';
     board[2] = '3';
     board[3] = '4';
     board[4] = '5';
     board[5] = '6';
     board[6] = '7';
     board[7] = '8';
     board[8] = '9';

     board2[0] = '1'; //sets up the board
     board2[1] = '2';
     board2[2] = '3';  
     board2[3] = '4';
     board2[4] = '5';
     board2[5] = '6';
     board2[6] = '7';
     board2[7] = '8';
     board2[8] = '9';

     board3[0] = '1'; //sets up the board
     board3[1] = '2';
     board3[2] = '3';
     board3[3] = '4';  
     board3[4] = '5';
     board3[5] = '6';
     board3[6] = '7';
     board3[7] = '8';
     board3[8] = '9';

     srand(time(NULL)); //seeds with clock
     rn = (rand() %2); 

     if (rn == 0){ //rnadom x and o and who goes first
            turn = 0; // cpu goes first
            xo[0] = 'x'; //comp = x
            xo[1] = 'o'; //human = o
             cout << "\nYou are 'O'" << endl; 
          }else{
              turn = 1; //play goes first
              xo[0] = 'o'; //comp = o
              xo[1] = 'x'; // human = x
              cout << "\nYou are 'X'" << endl; 
              }

     display(); //sends to display function
     }

void TTT::display(){

     cout << "" << endl; 
     for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) //for all spots on board
    {


        if ( (i+1) % 3 == 0 ) // ends dont get |
        {
            cout << board[i] << endl; //print number
        }
        else 
        {

            cout << board[i] << " | "; //print number then border
        }
   }

     cout << "" << endl; 
     cout << "\t";
     for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) //for all spots on board
    {


        if ( (i+1) % 3 == 0 ) // ends dont get |
        {

            cout << board2[i] << endl; //print number
            cout << "\t";
        }
        else 
        {

            cout << board2[i] <<    " | "; //print number then border
        }


   }

   cout << "" << endl; 
     cout << "\t\t";
     for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) //for all spots on board
    {


        if ( (i+1) % 3 == 0 ) // ends dont get |
        {

            cout << board3[i] << endl; //print number
            cout << "\t\t";
        }
        else 
        {

            cout << board3[i] <<    " | "; //print number then border
        }


   }
   cout << "" << endl;

    CPUClass cc;

    if (full == 27){ //if board is full
    check(won); //check if game has been won/tied
        }
    else{

         if (turn%2 == 0){ //decides whos turn it is
             player();
             }else{
                 //Comp cpu;
                 cout << "Computer is moving" ;
                 cc.cpu();//cput starts turn
          }

         }

     }

void TTT::player(){

  int w;
  int p;
  while (won != 1) //if no one has won loop
  {

     cout << "Which grid would you like to place your tile? [top=1 middle=2 bottom=3]" << endl;
     cin>> p; //which layer user wants to place

     if (p == 1){

           cout << "Enter the tile number you wish to place your marker" << endl;
           cin>>w; //in the layer of tile where to place

           if ((board[w-1] == 'x') || (board[w-1] == 'o')){ //checks if spot is open

            cout << "\nSomeone has already placed there! Please select a different tile\n";
            player();//loops back

        }else{
              board[w-1] = xo[1];//draws what player is (x or o) on tile picked
              turn ++; //turn over
              full ++; //add one to the board
              b1f++;
              display(); //go to display
              }

           }  

        else if (p == 2){

           cout << "Enter the tile number you wish to place your marker" << endl;
           cin>>w;

           if ((board2[w-1] == 'x') || (board2[w-1] == 'o')){ //checks if spot is open

            cout << "\nSomeone has already placed there! Please select a different tile\n";
            player();//loops back

        }else{
              board2[w-1] = xo[1];//draws what player is (x or o) on tile picked
              turn ++; //turn over
              full ++; //add one to the board
              b2f++;
              display(); //go to display
              }

           }  

     else if (p == 3){

           cout << "Enter the tile number you wish to place your marker" << endl;
           cin>>w;

           if ((board3[w-1] == 'x') || (board3[w-1] == 'o')){ //checks if spot is open

            cout << "\nSomeone has already placed there! Please select a different tile\n";
            player();//loops back

        }else{
              board3[w-1] = xo[1];//draws what player is (x or o) on tile picked
              turn ++; //turn over
              full ++; //add one to the board
              b3f;
              display(); //go to display
              }

           } 
           else{
                cout <<"Please select one of the options!\n\n" ; 
                player();
                } 

     }

  }
void TTT::cpu(){


     srand(time(NULL)); //seeds with clock
     rc = (rand() %9); //8 spots on board 0-8
     int bc;

     if (b1f == 9){ //if a board is filled pick another one
          bc = 1+(rand() %2);
      }
      else if (b3f == 9){
           bc = (rand() %2);
           }
      else if (b2f == 9){
           bc = (rand() %2);
           if (bc == 1){
                  bc = 2;
                  }
           }
      else {
           bc = (rand() %3); //else just randomly pick one
           }

     if (bc == 0){

     if ((board[rc] == 'x' ) || ( board[rc] == 'o')){

         Sleep(100); //seeded by time. So to prevent memory overflow pause before getting a new random number
         cpu(); //loops and finds a new spot

         }else{
           turn++; //ends turn
           full ++; //add one to board
           b1f++;
           board[rc] = xo[0]; // draw what cpu is on tile selected
           Sleep(800); //sleeps for 800ms, gives more realistic playing
           display(); //displays board
         }

     }

     else if (bc == 1){

          if ((board2[rc] == 'x' ) || ( board2[rc] == 'o')){

         Sleep(100); //seeded by time. So to prevent memory overflow pause before getting a new random number
         cpu(); //loops and finds a new spot

         }else{
           turn++; //ends turn
           full ++; //add one to board
           b2f++;
           board2[rc] = xo[0]; // draw what cpu is on tile selected
           Sleep(800); //sleeps for 800ms, gives more realistic playing
           display(); //displays board
         }

     }

          else if (bc == 2){

               if ((board3[rc] == 'x' ) || ( board3[rc] == 'o')){

         Sleep(100); //seeded by time. So to prevent memory overflow pause before getting a new random number
         cpu(); //loops and finds a new spot

         }else{
           turn++; //ends turn
           full ++; //add one to board
           b3f++;
           board3[rc] = xo[0]; // draw what cpu is on tile selected
           Sleep(800); //sleeps for 800ms, gives more realistic playing
           display(); //displays board
         }

     }

               }



void TTT::check(int wo){

     //horizontal win
      if ((board[0] == 'x') && (board[1] == 'x') && (board[2] == 'x')){

                   if (rn == 0){
                          cp++;
                          }else{
                                pp++;
                                }

                   }


      if ((board[6] == 'x') && (board2[4] == 'x') && (board3[2] == 'x')){


          if (rn == 0){
                          cp++;
                          }else{
                                pp++;
                                }
          }

////////////////more checking goes here, deleted because it's too long

              wo =1;
              cout << "\nGame Over!\n" ;

              cout << "\nScore: Player - "<<pp<<" Computer - "<<cp<<"\n" ;

              if (pp == cp){ //if points are =
                     cout << "You tied!\n" ;
                     }
              else if (pp > cp){ //if player points are greater, player wins
                   cout << "You won!\n" ;
                   }
              else if (pp < cp){
                   cout << "You lose!\n" ;
                   }

              int c;
           cout<<"\nPlay again? [1] for yes anything else to exit\n" ;
           cin >> c;

           if (c == 1){ //if user enters 1 then reset the game
                 setup();
                 }
           else{//else exit
           exit(0);

              }
     }
```

Comment: Well, you don't tell us what the error is, so how should we know?  Is it a compile-time or run-time error?

Comment: I did, I said that it plays fine but then the board displays junk code once it is the cpu() turn. No other errors.

Comment: You don't show us the code in which you're using to print anything, and "junk code" isn't necessarily helpful.  You seem to assume your problem is with one thing and have given us a lot of code, but haven't really shown anyone enough to make their own diagnosis.  When you're unable to figure it out on your own, you need to share everything that makes you think there's a problem and let others make their own diagnosis based on the facts, rather than based on your assumptions of what might be wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking if I did inhertiance right. Full code added

Comment: What are `CPUClass` and `CPUClass2` suppose to do for you? you are not doing inheritance correctly.

Comment: also class `cc` never has the `setup()` called so the board internally  will have garbage until you do. Do you want to share the board between the CPUClass ?

Comment: @corn3lius I edited my post. My cpu(); function is moved from the main class to there. CPUClass2 will hold a new cpu2() function. The program will have the two cpu's play each other. And yes I want to share the board.

Answer (score 0):

inheritance is a way to establish 'Is-a' relationships between classes in your main you create a `TTT` do you mean to instantiate the derived classes `CPUClass`

```
TTT ttt; // Creates a tic tac toe board
CPUClass cc; // Creates a derived tic tac toe board
```

ttt and cc have no knowledge of each other they aren't even playing on the same board.

perhaps you mean to create a `player` class and derive a human/computer variant?

I don't think inheritance will help you here.? I think what you need is a options for PvP PvC and CvC?

in the `display` loop here get rid of the new board `CPUClass` and use the one we are in.

```
if (full == 27){ //if board is full
   check(won); //check if game has been won/tied  
}
else{
   if (turn%2 == 0){ //decides whos turn it is
      player();  
   }else{
      cpu(); //cput starts turn
   }

   // Should be this. 
   int currentPlayer= turn % 2; 
   if( playerIsCpu(currentPlayer) ){ // create a function to return if this player is a cpu 
      cpu(currentPlayer); // cpu makes move for player 1..2
   } else{
      player( currentPlayer); // player 1..2 is presented with a move.
   } 
}
```